# Magento Cart-dropdown on product add button

Tags: magento-1.9, module, event-observer, addtocart

As title suggests I am trying to get a cart-dropdown when product gets added to the basket. My files are set as below, please advice where could this possibly be going wrong as I can't get this to work. I am using Magento 1.9.4

/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<events>
<checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    <observers>
        <Namespace_TriggerName>
            <type>singleton</type>       
            <class>Namespace_TriggerName_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>opencartafteradd</method>
        </Namespace_TriggerName>
    </observers>
</checkout_cart_product_add_after>
</events>
```

/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php

class Namespace_TriggerName_Model_Observer
{
public function opencartafteradd($observer) {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $product = $event->getProduct(); 
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setOpenMinicart('ON');
 }
}
```

/app/design/frontend/theme/default/template/page/html/head.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $v = jQuery.noConflict();
$v(document).ready(function() {
    var screen_width = $v(window).width();
    var openminicart = '<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getOpenMinicart();?>';
    if (screen_width > 780) {
        if (openminicart == 'ON') {
                jQuery("#header-cart").slideToggle('slow');
                jQuery("#header-cart").addClass('skip-active');


                setTimeout(function() {
                    jQuery("#header-cart").slideUp('fast');
                    $k('#header-cart').removeClass('skip-active');
                }, 4000);


        <?php Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsOpenMinicart();?>

        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrip code as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $v = jQuery.noConflict();
$v(document).ready(function() {
    var screen_width = $v(window).width();
    var openminicart = '<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getOpenMinicart();?>';
    if (screen_width > 780) {
        if (openminicart == 'ON') {
                $v("#header-cart").slideToggle('slow');
                $v("#header-cart").addClass('skip-active');


                setTimeout(function() {
                    $v("#header-cart").slideUp('fast');
                    $v('#header-cart').removeClass('skip-active');
                }, 4000);


        <?php Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsOpenMinicart();?>

        }
    }
});
</script>
```

$k instead of $v simple typo mistake

Comment: Am still not seeing any results, on when inspecting the JS element the openminicart variable is empty? Could there be a different session query?